# Remove emtpy raster - stars package R

Tags: r-stars

I have loaded a raster using `stars` package and then created tiles over the raster. Now i subset the raster based on these tile.

```
tiles[[i]] <- st_bbox(c(xmin=x0,ymin=y0,xmax=x1,ymax=y1),crs=st_crs(r))
crop_tiles[[i]] <- r[tiles[[i]]]
```

Here `r` is raster loaded using `read_stars("filename.tif")`.

Now i want to remove among the `crop_tiles` the empty ones. i.e the tiles where the raster values are NA

Answer (score 0):

You can check if all values of a `stars` object named `r` are `NA` with:

```r
all(is.na(r[[1]]))
```

then remove those tiles where the above is equal to `TRUE`.

For more specific code, please provide reproducible sample data in your question, thanks.

Comment: Does that also work the other way round? I have missing time steps in my data and need to fill in blank layers.

Comment: @JoanneDemmler Interesting question! First thought would be to loop over the vector dates, for each date `i` check if it exist in your raster: if it does then keep it, if it doesn't then create an empty raster. In the end, combine all resulting bands. If you can post an example in a separate question I'll try to prepare sample code.